# taskset dose not change CPU allocated to process

Tags: cpu, process

I changed CPU affinity of a process with taskset

```
sudo taskset -cp 0-10 2275
pid 2275's current affinity list: 0-10
```

but PSR of this process dosn't changed

```
ps -o psr -p 2275
PSR
 51
```

as I know after running taskset this process should be on one of the first 10 CPUs, but it is not